# How do I group by Week and Year, and depending on that, assign values to a third column having 'N' as all values initially?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, assign

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. I created a new column and assigned all values as 'N' to it.

Assume that first two columns have some random info, Column3 = Year, Column4= week No., Now Column5 =week-ES (initally assigned all 'N')should be equal to 'Week No.' for the recent 5 weeks, and should be equal to 'Pastwk' for all weeks before that. How can I use group by along with the top 5 weeks clause? How do I do that? I used this code, But did not get desire result. the desired result is the table below:

```
    df.sort_values(['Year','Week No.'],ascending=[False,False],inplace = True)
df['Week-ES'] = 'N'
df = df.groupby(['Year','Week No.']).size()
df['Week-ES'][:5]= df['Week No.'][:5]
#for i in range(5):
#    df.loc[df['Week-ES'].index == i, 'Week-ES'] = df['Week No.'].iloc[i]   
df.iloc[5:]['Week-ES'] = 'Past WK'
```

| Col1 | Col2 | Year | WeekNo. | Week-ES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | v2 | 2020 | 48 | Recent |
| v2 | v3 | 2020 | 47 | Recent |
| v3 | v4 | 2020 | 47 | Recent |
| v4 | v5 | 2020 | 46 | Recent |
| v5 | v6 | 2020 | 40 | Pastwk |
| v6 | v7 | 2019 | 52 | PastWk |

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Done, check please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is convert values to week periods, subtract 5 Weeks and compare by weeks periods from datetimes from columns `Year` and `Week` by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater or equal and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
last = pd.to_datetime('now').to_period('W') - 5
print (last)
2020-11-09/2020-11-15

s = df['Year'].astype(str).add(df['Week'].astype(str).add('-1'))
dates = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y%W-%w').dt.to_period('W')
df['C'] = np.where(dates.ge(last), 'Recent', 'Pastwk')

print (df)
   Year  Week       C
0  2020    48  Recent
1  2020    47  Recent
2  2020    47  Recent
3  2020    46  Recent
4  2020    40  Pastwk
5  2019    52  Pastwk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

# Get current week number and current year
current_week = datetime.date.today.isocalendar()[1]
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year

df['C'] = np.where(((df['Week'] >= current_week - 5) & (df['Year'] == current_year)), 'Recent', 'Pastwk')
```

You then have to manage when the year is 2021, and you are in January, cause current_week can be = 1 but the recent weeks won't be -5, -4, ... but 53, 52, etc.

Comment: yes, exactly this is problem with compare by numbers. So better is compare weeks periods.

Comment: That's why I sorted the year and week values. Now I want to assign 'recent' to top 5 weeks